# Track to object's surface

Tags: mesh, camera, constraints

I have a camera which is following a path. This path is surrounding a "large" u-shaped object (it's not a large object, but the camera is following it closely. Think of somebody scanning a house with a phone from a meter away), and I would like the camera to point at the object. If I use the `track to` constraint to target my object, the camera points to the object center, so if the camera is in the concave part of the object it points outside it (to the "center" of the object). is it possible to have the camera track to the surface of the object itself, without using keyframes and interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what it is you want to point the camera at.

Do you want to point the camera at the nearest surface point to the camera?  That's doable.

Snap cursor to camera, then create two empties.  We'll name one "trackTarget" and the other "cameraParent."  Parent camera and trackTarget to cameraParent.  Give trackTarget a shrinkwrap constraint targeting the object you wish to track.  Then give camera a track to constraint targeting trackTarget:

[image]

Now, rather than moving the camera, we'll move cameraParent, and camera and trackTarget will follow; trackTarget will then jump to the closest point on the mesh, and the camera will track that point.

Note that tracking the nearest surface point of the mesh might not be such a hot idea.  It can easily lead to poor interpolation when you consider that the mesh is actually made out of flat polygons.  But to me, it sounds like the closest thing to what you're asking for.